# Merge Join/Stream Lookup Pentaho Issue

Tags: sql, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I've got this question:

I've got two sources in SOURCE and COMPARISON and i've tried a Merge Join Step / Multiway merge join (in INNER option) / Stream Lookup. the image shows what I am facing.

[Issue]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQUPm.png

What should I use to the get the expected result in Pentaho or maybe using SQL to solve this issue.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicates in your COMPARISON table, so you'll need an **Unique rows** step before the Join step to be sure you only get one row for the A2-B2-C2-D2 key.

The unique rows also needs the streaming of rows sorted, so you only need one **Sort rows** step after querying the COMPARISON table and before the Unique rows, the Unique rows step will output the rows sorted. Another Sort rows step will be needed for the stream of data coming from the query to the SOURCE table before the Join of both streams of data.